# Bytes received in http are of variable sizes. Can I assume words "GET" or POST" or ,"DELETE" will be delivered to my same read() function call

Tags: c, sockets, http, ubuntu

Bytes received in http request are of variable sizes in read() function call.

Can I atleast assume:

```
3 characters word: "GET"
4 characters word: POST" 
6 characters word: "DELETE"
```

will be  delivered to my same read() function call

Or can I get `GE` in first read and `T` in second read to make the "GET" word of HTTP get requests.

Can any one please tell me this?

I am using linux kernel  `5.11.0-36-generic` with command `uname -r`
may be kernel version info needed to tell for read system call question specific to `http` protocol or may be not

Comment: "Can I atleast assume:" Basically... No. Do not assume anything. Very likely? yes. Sure? No!

Comment: @Gerhardh so it has to be interesting way to do it, is it doable to read all individual get request data if I construct received data and check for valid string at each step.

Comment: You need to collect incoming data until you got enough to decide whether the data is a valid request. Then handle or discard that request.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't think I can do this in single threaded program. because my single threaded server will mix up request data from different users connections . what do u think  I am getting it right? To handle each request I need to fork another thread and communicate in request specific thread. Is it right thinking?

Comment: Yes, I think it is common practice to create a thread per connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I atleast assume: will be delivered to my same read() function call

No.

> can I get GE in first read and T in second read to make the "GET" word of HTTP get requests.

Yes.

---

Well, it seems like this answer deserves a little more text. HTTP transport protocol is a protocol that functions on application layer in ISO/[OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). There are no requirements from HTTP on what happens in other layers, so transport layer can be anything there is, and the message can arrive in any fragments it wants, as long as the message is full when it's getting to application layer.

Because there are no requirements, it's unrelated to `read()` calls that operate with specific thing that transports the data. While some interfaces guarantee that you get data written with one `write()` call with one `read()` call, for example `fifo()` up to specific size, there are protocols that do not guarantee that in any way.

Still, it's unrelated. HTTP does not care in what chunks the data are transmitted, they can be transmitted byte by byte, or two messages at a time, don't care. *When* [the application layer message is fully transmitted](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.1), *then* the data are getting parsed by the application layer as HTTP.

Because there are no requirements, you can't assume that they should be delivered by same `read()` call. Anyway, you should instead assume that it *may* happen that reading HTTP-message will require multiple `read()` calls, also assume that it may happen that `read()` can fail with `EAGAIN` and needs to be repeated anyway.

Comment: @user786you're litteraly asking "Can any one please tell me this?", and KamilCuk answer exactly what you have precisly asked. So why are you commenting like his answer didn't help you ? Or am I missing a point ?

Comment: @user786 see small edit